# Consolidate List instead of having Each map or set

Tags: java

I have an excel file (.xls) which has several sheets

One primary sheet and rest are secondary sheets

Example, one of the primary sheet column value is being referred in secondary sheet

Primary Sheet has column:  Id, Description, Instruction 
1st Second Sheet:  Id, Action -> This id will be the primary sheet id
2nd Second Sheet:  Id, Action -> This id will be the primary sheet id
...
goes on..
....

How to get a consolidate list of items to run the instruction ???

Assume 5 items has values in 5 diff sheets which has instructions from primary sheet

from 1st sheet 1 item, from second sheet 1 item and goes on

Assume 5 items out of which first 3 items in first sheet and 2 from diff sheets which has instructions from primary sheet

Just like to have a list and do a for loop to iterate and run the instructions

Instead of having multiple maps and or set for each sheet

Thanks.

Comment: That's quite vague and some example or code would definitely help. I'd probably use _one_ map for the items but that's as much as I can tell without better understanding of your problem and what you've already tried to solve it.

Comment: Read Primary and create a Map Id and Type
Read Secondary Sheets and Create a Map Id and Type

Whenever we get an info to process
Iterate Primary to know the Id
Iterate Secondary to know the exact details

Reason: The number of columns are dynamic for each sheet. One sheet may have 10 columns and another may have 50 columns

Comment: In that case I'd create a class that represents the values of the single map that's used and that contains the data found on the secondary sheets. What that class should look like would depend on the data and other requirements (e.g. is the number of columns fixed, capped to a maximum or totally dynamic? Is the content of each column known without looking that the sheet itself? Is there a way to identify what a column represents? Does that even matter, what's done with that data?)